# How to broadcast using the method of RTP / AVP in VLC

Tags: vlc, rtp

I need to broadcast a video stream using RTP/AVP method. How to do this with VLC?

I tried to set destination IP like `224.0.0.0`, and SAP notification. But on the client I can't receive the video stream (`rtp://224.0.0.0:5004`). If I looked in wireshark i saw that the server is broadcasting and the client has connected to group `224.0.0.0`. But the video didn't receive on the client.

Answer (score 0):

how you confirmed that only Audio packets received? Wireshark with a udp.port==5004 filter?
Video stream maybe at udp.port==5006.